# Parallel Computation

Tags: parallelization

How can I modify this code in order to run in parallel? (It's some part of my main code)

```
LogNeg = {};
Do[LNeg = 0;
Do[Do[
  A = {{CoMat[[2*i - 1, 2*i - 1]], 
    CoMat[[2*i - 1, 2*i]]}, {CoMat[[2*i, 2*i - 1]], 
    CoMat[[2*i, 2*i]]}};

  B = {{CoMat[[2*j - 1, 2*j - 1]], 
    CoMat[[2*j - 1, 2*j]]}, {CoMat[[2*j, 2*j - 1]], 
    CoMat[[2*j, 2*j]]}};

  F = {{CoMat[[2*i - 1, 2*j - 1]], 
    CoMat[[2*i - 1, 2*j]]}, {CoMat[[2*i, 2*j - 1]], 
    CoMat[[2*i, 2*j]]}};

  S = ArrayFlatten[{{A, F}, {Transpose[F], B}}];

  v = eta /. 
   Solve[eta^4 - (Det[A] + Det[B] - 2*Det[F])*eta^2 + Det[S] == 0];

  LNeg += -Log2[Min[Abs[v], 1]], {j, i + 1, M}], {i, 1, M}];

  AppendTo[LogNeg, LNeg], {t, 0, tMax}];
```

I've used ParallelDo[], but It doesn't work.
Main code:
https://ufile.io/cmjj6

Thank you in advance

Comment: We cannot run this code without CoMat. Where exactly did you use ParallelDo?

Comment: @J42161217 CoMat is a 2M*2M square matrix of interpolating Functions. It's made by solving ODEs. The code is a big one, anyway, It's what I embedded above.

Comment: Did you try to substitute only the outer Do?

Comment: Yes, I did; Both outer Do' separately.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Could you add the exact code you tried and the error it produced to the question?

Comment: Added. The problem is taking very much time to give the result for big systems that I need. Using ParallelDo gives me wrong result, by the way, and surprisingly takes more time than ordinary code.

Comment: "Using ParallelDo gives me wrong result, by the way, and surprisingly takes more time than ordinary code." That's not uncommon as `Parallel` has a certain overhead. Certainly `AppendTo` will prevent good parallelisation, even if it will be set as shared variable with `SetSharedVariable`: One process has to wait for the other to get write access. But without _exact_ knowledge about `CoMat`, it is quite unlikely that an answer can be found.

Comment: Parallel seems to work only applied to the second Do

Comment: A better strategy would be to skip `AppendTo` and replace the outer `Do` by a `ParallelTable`, possibly with `Method -> "CoarsestGrained"`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You're right about `AppendTo`. Anyway, I'm using `ParallelTable` but I don't know why It lasts more. I'm checking `Det[A] + Det[B] - 2*Det[F]`; It gives me non-zero values.

Comment: @J42161217 Yes, but no progress anyway.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not parallelized, but tremendously faster. Most important are:

- The matrix `CoMat` is evaluated only once for each `t`. Inparticular, `CoMat2[t]` is explicitly defined as a function `t` to gai control over evaluation; and it returns the matrix `CoMat` already nicely partitioned for easy access.
- The function `sol` which solves the *symbolic* equation once and the time of definition.

This makes the execution ten times faster.

```
CoMat2[t_] = Partition[
   First[Cov[t] /. 
     NDSolve[{Join[DiffEq, InitialCond]}, Cov[t], {t, 0, tMax}]],
   {2, 2}, {2, 2}];
sol[p_, q_] = N[η /. Solve[η^4 - p η^2 + q == 0, η]];
result = Table[
     Mat = Developer`ToPackedArray[CoMat2[t]];
     Block[{A, detA, B, F, S},
      Sum[
       A = Mat[[i, i]];
       detA = Det[A];
       Sum[
        B = Mat[[j, j]];
        F = Mat[[i, j]];
        S = ArrayFlatten[{{A, F}, {Transpose[F], B}}];
        -Log2[Min[Abs[sol[(detA + Det[B] - 2*Det[F]), Det[S]]], 1]],
        {j, i + 1, M}],
       {i, 1, M}]
      ],
     {t, 0., tMax}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.327722

## Edit

I cannot speed up the `InterpolatingFunction`s, but the rest can be made much faster (and parallelized) with `Compile`:

```
Block[{MAT, i, j, A, B, F, S, vcode},
  A = {
    {Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 i - 1, 2 i - 1], Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 i - 1, 2 i]},
    {Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 i, 2 i - 1], Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 i, 2 i]}
    };
  B = {
    {Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 j - 1, 2 j - 1], Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 j - 1, 2 j]},
    {Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 j, 2 j - 1], Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 j, 2 j]}
    };
  F = {
    {Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 i - 1, 2 j - 1], Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 i - 1, 2 j]},
    {Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 i, 2 j - 1], Compile`GetElement[MAT, 2 i, 2 j]}
    };
  S = ArrayFlatten[{{A, F}, {Transpose[F], B}}];
  vcode = sol[(Det[A] + Det[B] - 2*Det[F]), Det[S]];
  
  cf = With[{code = vcode},
    Compile[{{MAT, _Real, 2}, {M, _Integer}},
     Block[{LNeg = 0.},
      Do[Do[
        LNeg -= Log2[Min[Abs[code], 1.]],
        {j, i + 1, M}], {i, 1, M}];
      LNeg
      ],
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
  ];
```

Now the computations:

```
CoMat[t_] = 
  First[Cov[t] /. 
    NDSolve[{Join[DiffEq, InitialCond]}, Cov[t], {t, 0, tMax}]];
Mat = Developer`ToPackedArray[
    Table[CoMat[t], {t, 0., tMax}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
result2 = cf[Mat, M]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[result - result2]]
```

> 0.123596
>
> 0.000423
>
> 6.24386*10^-11